# displaying matching id , flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter, I'm trying to show cards in categories, I've made a module with the categories and items, including id for the categories and matching id for the item(one item can be in multiple categories ) but I don't know how to sort them

this is the main screen

```dart
    Widget _buildIcon(int index) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          setState(() {
            _selectedIndex = index;
          String id =  DUMMY_CATEGORIES[index].id;
          print(id);
          });
        },
        child: Container(
          height: 45,
          width: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: _selectedIndex == index
                  ? Color.fromRGBO(126, 214, 223, 0.5)
                  : Color.fromRGBO(200, 214, 229,0.3),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(80)),
          child: Center(
            child: Text(
             DUMMY_CATEGORIES[index].title, style: TextStyle(color: _selectedIndex==index ?Color.fromRGBO(16, 172, 132, 1) : Colors.black, ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10, top: 20),
                alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    size: 25,
                  ),
                )),
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Text(
                  'Make it Bread',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                )),
          ],
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 30,
        ),
        SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: DUMMY_CATEGORIES
                .asMap()
                .entries
                .map((MapEntry map) => _buildIcon(map.key))
                .toList()
          ),

        ),
       NewMealIteam(),

      ],
    ),

    );
  }
}
```

and this is the item

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 45),

        child: Container(
          height: 450,
          //color: Colors.orange,
          child: ListView.builder(itemCount: mealList.length,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context ,int index){
            Meal mealLists = mealList[index];
        return Container(
          width: 280,
          child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: 450,
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
              padding:  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                color: Colors.red,
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/dough.png'
                ),fit: BoxFit.fill
              ),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    blurRadius: 2.0,
                    spreadRadius: 0.0,
                    offset: Offset(3.0, 2.0), // shadow direction: bottom right
                  )
                ],),


            ),

            Positioned(bottom :20 ,left: 20,child: Column(

              children: <Widget>[
                Container(width: 170,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25),
                  child: Text(mealLists.title,style: TextStyle(color:Colors.white,fontSize: 32),textAlign: TextAlign.start,overflow: TextOverflow.fade
                    ,),

                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                  child: Container(width:220,
                    child: Row(

                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Row(  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(Icons.schedule),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 6,
                            ),
                            Text('${mealLists.duration} min'),
                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Icon(Icons.work),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 8,
                            ),

                          ],
                        ),
                        Row(  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: <Widget>[
                           Icon(Icons.monetization_on),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 6,
                            ),
                            // Text('${durations} min'),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ))
          ],),
        );
          },
        ),
        ),

    );
  }
}
```

this is example for the module list

```dart
   Category(
      id: 'c1',
      title: 'sour bread',
   ),

   Meal(
      id: 'm1',
      categories: [
        'c1',
        'c2',
      ],
      title: 'Sour Dough',
   ),
```

thanks

Comment: What do you mean you don't know how to sort them? How do you *want* to sort them? What did you try and what failed? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Please Format you code properly and be clear with what you want , and please add the sample json data in correct format. so that i can tell you whats going wrong, or what to do.